# executionTimeout to send response

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpruntime, executiontimeout

When you set the httpRuntime executionTimeout, does that cut off a response that has already been partially sent to the client?

I've noticed in the IIS request queue that occasionally there are some requests that run for a lot longer than our executionTimeout setting and the state is SendResponse in the IIS Web Core module.  Does the executionTimeout include the time that it takes to send the response to the client?

The only documentation that I could find is on the following page in this snip, but it is from 2003 for older versions of IIS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx

> Request Execution Time. The number of milliseconds taken to execute the last request. In version 1.0 of the Framework, the execution time begins when the worker process receives the request, and stops when the ASP.NET ISAPI sends HSE_REQ_DONE_WITH_SESSION to IIS. For IIS version 5, this includes the time taken to write the response to the client, but for IIS version 6, the response buffers are sent asynchronously, and so the time taken to write the response to the client is not included.

The IIS version is 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 running an ASP.NET 4.5 web application and debug is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not addressing your question directly, but there is something that might help with your problem:

There's a `minBytesPerSecond` setting for setting a lower bound on transmission speed in [the `<webLimits>` section.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/weblimits) I suspect it was originally added as a defense against [SlowLoris,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)) but you can bump the value up to kick out users whose pipe can't support your site. The default value is 240, which is pretty low.